# Integrating react-three-drei with React Native for 3D Graphics

Tags: react-native, three.js, mobile-application, react-three-drei

I'm currently working on a project that involves creating a React Native application with some 3D graphics components. I've come across the `react-three-drei` library, which seems to offer a variety of useful components and utilities for working with `Three.js` in React applications.

I'm interested in using `react-three-drei` to enhance my React Native app's 3D capabilities, but I'm unsure about the compatibility between `react-three-drei`, designed for React with `Three.js`, and React Native's native rendering environment.

**Is it possible to use `react-three-drei` with React Native?** I know that React Native has different rendering mechanisms compared to a web browser, so I'm wondering if there's any compatibility or workaround for using this library in my mobile app.

**If it is possible, what are the steps to integrate `react-three-drei` with a React Native project?** Are there any special considerations, configuration, or limitations I should be aware of?

**Are there any alternatives or recommended libraries for working with 3D graphics in React Native?** If using react-three-drei is not feasible, I'd appreciate suggestions for other libraries or techniques that could help me achieve my goal of incorporating 3D graphics into my React Native app.

I'm eager to learn from the experiences of others who have attempted similar integration or who have expertise in both `react-three-drei` and React Native. Any insights, guidance, or resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can find some info here: https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/getting-started/installation#react-native